# Unity objects with flickering and noisy edges

Tags: unity, graphic-effects, noise

In our game which is still in early development we're (we, Unity rookies) facing this flickering issue occurring especially in edges which are very close to each other, but not limited to them. The problem worsens once the camera moves but in the idle state it's not also not working as expected.

Here is a video depicting the situation. Notice that once I disable the edge detection the problem improves some, but still persists.
https://youtu.be/EL28HORkbbU

Here are our Edge Detection settings

[image: Edge Detection settings]

Here is our PP anti-aliasing settings (We also tried FXAA but it gives worse results)
[image: PP antialiasing settings]

The buildings are natively modeled with ProBuilder.
Unity version: 2018.2.14f1

Is there a way to solve this issue to obtain smoothness in such edge detection cases? Are we missing something? We want to keep that visual style in which edges are drawn in black.